# Handle-based entity manager (that stores entities contiguously)

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I've created a generic data structure intended for game development entity management. It has some interesting properties:

- Entities are stored contiguously in an `std::vector`.
- Stored entities can be in one of three states: *alive*, *dead*, *unused*.
- Upon entity creation, a lightweight `Handle` object is returned:

  - The user can check whether the entity is alive or not from the handle.
  - The user can access the entity from the handle.
  - The user can *mark the entity as dead* from the handle.
- Every frame (or every time the user desires), calling `Manager::refresh()` deals with dead entities:

  1. The internal contiguous storage is sorted using entity state as the sorting predicate. *Alive* entities are placed at the beginning of the storage, *dead* entities are placed at the end. *Unused* entities stay in between.
  2. *Dead* entities get destroyed and their handles get invalidated.
  3. The manager iterates over *Alive* entities to update their handles (and keep them valid).

Example diagram:

> ```
> // Starting situation: we have 6 alive entities 
>
>
> Entity storage:  | A00 | A01 | A02 | A03 | A04 | A05 |
> Control storage: | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Index storage:   | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Counter storage: | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 |
>
>
>
> // Entity #04 is marked as `dead` (handle is still valid)
>
>                                             X
> Entity storage:  | A00 | A01 | A02 | A03 | A04 | A05 |  
> Control storage: | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Index storage:   | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Counter storage: | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 |
>
>
>
> // User calls `refresh()` - at the beginning of the method entities are sorted
> // along with their control indices
>
>                                                   X
> Entity storage:  | A00 | A01 | A02 | A03 | A05 | A04 |  
> Control storage: | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 005 | 004 |  
> Index storage:   | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Counter storage: | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 |
>
>
>
> // `refresh()` continues - dead entity data is destroyed, and dead entity 
> // counters are incremented to invalidate existing handles
> // Dead entities become unused entities now
>
>                                                   U
> Entity storage:  | A00 | A01 | A02 | A03 | A05 |     |  
> Control storage: | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Index storage:   | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Counter storage: | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 001 | 000 |
>
> // If an user queries an handle with index 004 to check the status of the 
> // entity, the incremented counter will make the user know the entity is now 
> // dead
>
>
>
> // `refresh()` continues - alive entities update their indices/controllers
>
>                                                   U
> Entity storage:  | A00 | A01 | A02 | A03 | A05 |     |  
> Control storage: | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 005 | 004 |  
> Index storage:   | 000 | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 |  
> Counter storage: | 000 | 000 | 000 | 000 | 001 | 000 |
>
> // Now, accessing an handle pointing to A05 will access the 6th control storage
> // element, which contains 005, which is the new index of the A05 entity
> ```

---

```cpp
#include <SSVUtils/SSVUtils.hpp>

using Idx = std::size_t;
using Ctr = int;

template<typename> class Manager;

namespace Internal
{
    template<typename T> class Uncertain
    {
        private:
            ssvu::AlignedStorageBasic<T> storage;

        public:
            template<typename... TArgs> inline void init(TArgs&&... mArgs) noexcept(ssvu::isNothrowConstructible<T>())
            {
                new (&storage) T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...);
            }
            inline void deinit() noexcept(ssvu::isNothrowDestructible<T>()) { get().~T(); }

            inline T& get() noexcept                { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(storage); }               
            inline const T& get() const noexcept    { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(storage); }             
    };

    template<typename T> class Atom 
    {
        template<typename> friend class Manager;

        private:
            enum class State : int {Alive = 0, Unused = 1, Dead = 2};
            Idx ctrlIdx;
            State state{State::Unused};
            Uncertain<T> data;

            // Initializes the internal data
            template<typename... TArgs> inline void initData(TArgs&&... mArgs) noexcept(ssvu::isNothrowConstructible<T>())
            {
                SSVU_ASSERT(state == State::Unused);
                data.init(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...);
            }

            // Deinitializes the internal data
            inline void deinitData() noexcept(ssvu::isNothrowDestructible<T>())
            { 
                SSVU_ASSERT(state != State::Unused);
                data.deinit();
            }

        public:
            inline Atom() = default;
            inline Atom(Atom&&) = default;
            inline Atom& operator=(Atom&&) = default;

            inline T& getData() noexcept                { SSVU_ASSERT(state != State::Unused); return data.get(); }             
            inline const T& getData() const noexcept    { SSVU_ASSERT(state != State::Unused); return data.get(); } 
            inline void setDead() noexcept              { state = State::Dead; }

            // Disallow copies
            inline Atom(const Atom&) = delete;
            inline Atom& operator=(const Atom&) = delete;
    };
}

template<typename T> class Handle
{
    template<typename> friend class Manager;

    private:
        using AtomType = typename Internal::Atom<T>;

        Manager<T>& manager;
        Idx ctrlIdx;
        Ctr ctr;

        inline Handle(Manager<T>& mManager, Idx mCtrlIdx, Ctr mCtr) noexcept 
            : manager(mManager), ctrlIdx{mCtrlIdx}, ctr{mCtr} { }       

        template<typename TT> inline TT getAtomImpl() noexcept
        {
            SSVU_ASSERT(isAlive());
            return manager.getAtomFromController(manager.controllers[ctrlIdx]);
        }

    public:
        inline AtomType& getAtom() noexcept             { return getAtomImpl<AtomType&>(); }
        inline const AtomType& getAtom() const noexcept { return getAtomImpl<const AtomType&>(); }
        inline T& get() noexcept                        { return getAtom().getData(); }
        inline const T& get() const noexcept            { return getAtom().getData(); }
        bool isAlive() const noexcept;
        void destroy() noexcept;
};

template<typename T> class Manager
{
    template<typename> friend class Handle;

    private:
        struct Controller { Idx idx; Ctr ctr; };
        using AtomType = typename Internal::Atom<T>;
        using AtomState = typename AtomType::State;

        std::vector<AtomType> atoms;
        std::vector<Controller> controllers;
        Idx size{0u};

        inline void growStorage(std::size_t mOldSize, std::size_t mNewSize)
        {
            SSVU_ASSERT(mNewSize >= 0 && mNewSize >= mOldSize);

            atoms.resize(mNewSize);
            controllers.resize(mNewSize);

            // Initialize resized storage
            for(; mOldSize < mNewSize; ++mOldSize)
            {
                atoms[mOldSize].ctrlIdx = mOldSize;                 
                controllers[mOldSize].idx = mOldSize;
            }
        }

        inline void growIfNeeded()
        {
            constexpr std::size_t resizeAmount{10};

            // If the first free index is valid, return
            auto oldSize(atoms.size());
            if(oldSize > size) return;

            // Calculate new size and grow storage
            growStorage(oldSize, oldSize + resizeAmount);
        }

        inline void destroy(Idx mCtrlIdx) noexcept
        {           
            getAtomFromController(controllers[mCtrlIdx]).setDead();
        }

        inline Controller& getControllerFromAtom(const AtomType& mAtom)         { return controllers[mAtom.ctrlIdx]; }
        inline AtomType& getAtomFromController(const Controller& mController)   { return atoms[mController.idx]; }

        inline void cleanUpMemory()
        {
            for(auto& a : atoms)                
                if(a.state != AtomState::Unused) 
                {
                    a.deinitData();
                    a.state = AtomState::Unused;
                }           
        }

    public:
        inline Manager() = default;
        inline ~Manager() { cleanUpMemory(); }

        inline void clear() noexcept
        {
            cleanUpMemory();
            atoms.clear();
            controllers.clear();
            size = 0;
        }

        inline void reserve(std::size_t mSize) 
        { 
            growStorage(atoms.size(), mSize); 
        }

        template<typename... TArgs> inline Handle<T> createAtom(TArgs&&... mArgs)
        {
            // `size` may be greater than the sizes of the vectors - resize vectors if needed 
            growIfNeeded();

            // `size` now is the first empty valid index - we create our atom there
            atoms[size].initData(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...);
            atoms[size].state = AtomState::Alive;

            // Update the controller
            auto cIdx(atoms[size].ctrlIdx);
            auto& controller(controllers[cIdx]);
            controller.idx = size;
            ++controller.ctr;

            // Update current size
            ++size;

            return {*this, cIdx, controller.ctr};   
        }   

        inline void refresh()
        {
            // C++14: use polymorphic lambda
            ssvu::sortStable(atoms, [](const AtomType& mA, const AtomType& mB){ return mA.state < mB.state; });

            // Starting from the end, update dead entities and their controllers
            auto i(atoms.size() - 1);           
            for(; i > 0 && atoms[i].state == AtomState::Dead; --i)              
            {
                atoms[i].deinitData();
                atoms[i].state = AtomState::Unused;
                ++(getControllerFromAtom(atoms[i]).ctr);                
            }

            // Starting from the beginning, update alive entities and their controllers
            for(i = 0u; i <= atoms.size() && atoms[i].state == AtomState::Alive; ++i)           
                getControllerFromAtom(atoms[i]).idx = i;

            // Update current size
            size = i;
        }

        template<typename TFunc> inline void forEach(TFunc mFunc)
        {
            for(auto i(0u); i < size; ++i) mFunc(atoms[i].getData());
        }   
        template<typename TFunc> inline void forEachAtom(TFunc mFunc)
        {
            for(auto i(0u); i < size; ++i) mFunc(atoms[i]);
        }

        inline AtomType& getAtomAt(Idx mIdx) noexcept               { SSVU_ASSERT(mIdx < atoms.size()); return atoms[mIdx]; }
        inline const AtomType& getAtomAt(Idx mIdx) const noexcept   { SSVU_ASSERT(mIdx < atoms.size()); return atoms[mIdx]; }
        inline T& getDataAt(Idx mIdx) noexcept                      { return getAtomAt(mIdx).getData(); }
        inline const T& getDataAt(Idx mIdx) const noexcept          { return getAtomAt(mIdx).getData(); }

        inline std::size_t getSize() const noexcept { return size; }
};

template<typename T> inline bool Handle<T>::isAlive() const noexcept
{ 
    return manager.controllers[ctrlIdx].ctr == ctr;
}

template<typename T> inline void Handle<T>::destroy() noexcept
{ 
    return manager.destroy(ctrlIdx);
}
```

---

Example usage:

```cpp
Manager<std::string> mgr;

assert(mgr.getSize() == 0);

auto h0 = mgr.createAtom("hi");
auto h1 = mgr.createAtom("bye");
auto h2 = mgr.createAtom("hello");
auto h3 = mgr.createAtom("goodbye");

assert(mgr.getSize() == 4);

h0.get() += " sir";
h1.destroy();
h2.get() += " madam;
h3.destroy();

mgr.refresh();

assert(!h1.isAlive());
assert(!h3.isAlive());
assert(h0.get() == "hi sir");
assert(h2.get() == "hello madam");
assert(mgr.getSize() == 2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few minor things I've found:

- This could be a maintenance issue:

  ```
  inline void cleanUpMemory()
  {
      for(auto& a : atoms)                
          if(a.state != AtomState::Unused) 
          {
              a.deinitData();
              a.state = AtomState::Unused;
          }           
  }
  ```

  There should still be curly braces with the `for` loop.  You already use them elsewhere, so I don't need to go further into that.

  I also don't think this needs to be `inline`.  Even when the keyword is needed, it's primarily done with single-line functionality.  If the compiler decides to inline it anyway, then it will.
- This comment is useless:

  ```
  // Update current size
  ++size;
  ```

  `size` is clearly being updated, or specifically, incremented.  Comments should be useful and not state the obvious.
- It may be a little more readable to have the `template` statement on a separate line from the class or function statement:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  class Uncertain
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Overall, I like your liberal use of C++11 style. One minor nitpick about the use of `inline` that occurs all over the place:

```
class Bla
{
public:
    inline void fun() { /* implementation */ }
    ^^^^^^
};
```

the use of `inline` is superfluous here since anything defined in-class is implicitly inline, and furthermore, `inline` is only a compiler *hint* for actual inlining (the main use of `inline` is to prevent ODR violations in header files).